# https need tls with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, keystore, cloudflare

I use spring boot 2.6.
I need to use ssl. So i created a key and

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tf -keystore tf.jks -storepass changeit -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

in properties

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=tf.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.keyAlias=tf
```

On the firewall side i done in almalinux

```
firewall-offline-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8443
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Application start without issue.

When I try to reach the application in the browser with https (with name and ip), I get

> Bad Request 
> This combination of host and port requires TLS.

In the log, I see

> Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 / (https
> Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) with context path ''

I use cloudflare dns

Comment: That error usually means the client is still trying to use HTTP instead of HTTPS. Are you sure the client is using HTTPS?

Comment: i used https in the browser

Comment: Then perhaps Cloudflare is terminating TLS before it reaches your application. Can you reproduce when running locally?

Comment: Also, just noticed you're forwarding port 80 (typically HTTP) to 8443 (typically HTTPS). Did you mean to forward 443 (HTTPS) to 8443 (HTTPS)?